# Using Custom Contact Layout in Google Contact

Tags: google-contacts

I want to manage Google Contacts with custom fields.

I know I can do it one by one, adding for each contact the custom fields that I need.
What I am looking for is a way to "use a template" so that Google Contact create my custom fields for all contacts.

It would be acceptable to do it from Outlook or another client, and then Sync with Google Contact.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are three basic ways to sync Google Contacts

- Using [CardDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDav).
- Using [Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync) (requires 
  Google Apps Unlimited, Google Apps for Work and Google Apps for
  Government accounts and a supported version of Outlook)
- Using the [Contacts API V3 - Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) (requires programing skills)